# SQL get results by condition from multi table joibs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get results that match a join condition from 1 or more tables.

I want the query to return only the products which their color is blue AND white AND their brand is my_brand_1

Here is my fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urA3kbd9JeYed7xGUEWref/2

```
CREATE TABLE colors (
  prodoct_id CHAR(250),
  name CHAR(250)
);
INSERT INTO colors (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_1', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_1', 'white');
INSERT INTO colors (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_2', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_2', 'green');

CREATE TABLE brands (
  prodoct_id CHAR(250),
  name CHAR(250)
);
INSERT INTO brands (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_1', 'my_brand_1');
INSERT INTO brands (prodoct_id, name) VALUES ('prodoct_2', 'my_brand_2');

CREATE TABLE prodocts (
  prodoct_id CHAR(250)
);
INSERT INTO prodocts (prodoct_id) VALUES ('prodoct_1');
INSERT INTO prodocts (prodoct_id) VALUES ('prodoct_2');

SELECT 
    prodocts.prodoct_id
FROM 
    prodocts
    
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
    colors
 ON (colors.name = 'blue' AND prodocts.prodoct_id = colors.prodoct_id)
     AND (colors.name = 'white' AND prodocts.prodoct_id = colors.prodoct_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN     
    brands
 ON (brands.name = 'my_brand_1' AND brands.prodoct_id = colors.prodoct_id)
```

Comment: this is a pretty weird DB layout, shouldn't the product table hold a key to brands and color, instead of the other way around? Is there a reason for this? it would make more sense just to add color and brand into product

Comment: No because you can have more than 1 color or brand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My query return only the `products` that are `blue` and `white` and their brand is `my_brand_1` (return only products that meet all three conditions):

```
SELECT p.prodoct_id
FROM prodocts p
INNER JOIN colors c1 ON p.prodoct_id = c1.prodoct_id AND c1.name = 'blue'
INNER JOIN colors c2 ON p.prodoct_id = c2.prodoct_id AND c2.name = 'white'
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.prodoct_id = p.prodoct_id AND b.name = 'my_brand_1';
```

Your query was close to the require result.

**UPDATED**: "with a single join for each table"

```
SELECT prodoct_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.prodoct_id, b.name, c.name
      FROM prodocts p
      INNER JOIN colors c ON p.prodoct_id = c.prodoct_id AND (c.name = 'blue' OR  c.name = 'white')
      INNER JOIN brands b ON b.prodoct_id = p.prodoct_id AND b.name = 'my_brand_1') AS sq
GROUP BY prodoct_id    
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

OR

Assuming you don't have color rows repeated.

```
SELECT p.prodoct_id
FROM prodocts p
INNER JOIN (SELECT prodoct_id
            FROM colors 
            WHERE name IN ('blue', 'white')
            GROUP BY prodoct_id
            HAVING count(*) = 2) AS c ON p.prodoct_id = c.prodoct_id
INNER JOIN brands b ON b.prodoct_id = p.prodoct_id AND b.name = 'my_brand_1';
```

Comment: I want something with a single join for each table, is it possible?

Comment: Yes @dasdasd, I updated my answer. There are different ways to make the query you want.